# Is this a common design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, f#, functional-programming

i use the following pattern/style alot in my applications/programs and want to know if this is a common pattern that i don't know.

When i must write an app that is like a big function that get the input data from different sources, do the processing and create the output. Like the IPO Model (input-process-output).

I have one class/type that represents only my state/data which has no logic. Most of the time i name it Context, ExecutionContext or RuntimeContext. I also have multiple classes/types that contains only logic as stateless funtions (in C# static methods in static classes). After my entrypoint of the app, i create the context at first and use it then as arguments for my functions. The context holds the complate state/data of the app and all my static functions/methods manipulate the context. At the end of the functions chain and the call/execution is done and the context holds the final state if i need outputdata.

I try to create a picture that visualize these approach

[image]

The advantage of these pattern is

1. i can simple test my logic (small pieces of static functions) with
   unittest
2. it is not so hard to use concurrent code (only the context need threadsafe code)
3. dependencies to other systems a mostly decoupled as abstractions (interfaces) in the context (for example an IDbContext). That make the testing of a bigger scope simple

And here is now my question. Is this a common pattern? When yes, how is it called?

Thanks for every hint! :)

regards

Comment: You probably want to take this to the software engineering exchange.

Comment: Can you support your diagram with a sample code. Your diagram doesn't show interfaces /classes as you describe in your text.

Comment: Probably thr best fits will be Abstract Factory or Chain of Responsibility from what I can see. Lots of stuff to explore here though.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af062e83-3e61-45d4-aeaa-d30b4366c6a2/the-23-gang-of-four-design-patterns-cheat-sheet?forum=architecturegeneral

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/gang-of-four-gof-design-patterns-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a [Dataflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming).

The functions are black boxes which act on the data provided to it. Dataflows are turing complete, and can even model traditional imperative flow control structures.

Comment: Thx for the hint Asti. The link helps me in my search

Comment: @user1481065 I've implemented a full dataflow system with the necessary properties to simulate control flow structures. Message me if you want more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

When you issue a request to ASP.NET MVC, it has an entry and at the end it returns an output. ASP.NET MVC is open source and there are tons of diagrams which explain the whole pipeline and how it works. It is also very customizable so developers can plug their own classes in, intercept certain events, hook into certain parts (filters, authentication, authorization etc.)

If I were you I would start looking into that and borrow some ideas from it. You don't event have to look at the source code. You can start by looking at the diagrams for the pipeline and see what it is doing and how it is doing it.

Right now your code is just functions which are executed in a serial manner. If you want to use Object Orientation, take advantage of interfaces and allow customization, event interception, hooking etc. then it will be difficult.

[Here](https://www.asp.net/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf) is the diagram in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's common in IoC-style apps, where services/repositories are singletons and, as so, stateless.

The advantage of this approach is that it saves a lot of memory and some time (no need for new instances of components to be spawned). Disadvantage is that you somehow lose the OOP aproach and also is hard to maintance in bigger picture without strong interfaces support and IoC/Dependency Injection container.

Also look at [ThreadLocal<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) mechanism build into .NET - that way you don't need to pass your context explicit, but rather than that access thred-scoped global variable that contains it (but then - you need to watch out when branching threads, another topic that IoC/DI handles).